# Eclipse or JBossStudio (cannot be resolved to a type)

Tags: eclipse, jboss

Can someone explain to me why I get this kind of error in the JBoss studio (eclipse)?

[Jobss studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1lmI.png)

I'm able to compile the source code with mvn clean install, but in the source code editor I got some "warning" like "ServiceRequest cannot be resolved to a type".

Comment: try to clean projects via "Project -> Clean..." menu

Comment: Have tried but is the same.

Comment: And what about "Maven" -> "Update project" ?